# Adding Standard Deviation for Each Unique Factor Grouping

Tags: r

I'm trying to bring in the standard deviation for each unique factor grouping in my data. I've researched techniques using the data.table package and the plyr package and haven't had any luck. Here is a basic example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
Group  Hours
  120     45
  120     60
  120     54
  121     33
  121     55
  121     40
```

I'm trying to turn the above into:

```
Group  Hours     SD
  120     45  7.343
  120     60  7.343
  120     54  7.343
  121     33  9.833
  121     55  9.833
  121     40  9.833
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base solution (assuming your data called `df`)

```
transform(df, SD = ave(Hours, Group, FUN = sd))
```

---

`data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)  
setDT(df)[, SD := sd(Hours), by = Group]
```

---

`dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(SD = sd(Hours))
```

---

And here's a `plyr` solution (my first ever) as you asked for it

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(Group), mutate, SD = sd(Hours))
```

(It is better to avoid having both `plyr` and `dplyr` loaded at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, David, for your detailed response! I've used data.table to write what I'm looking for. Here is a snippet of my final script that I wrote using David's answer.

```
PayrollHoursSD <- as.data.table(PayrollHours2)[, SD := sd(TOTAL.HOURS), by = COMBO]
head(PayrollHoursSD)

#    COMBO    PAY.END.DATE  TOTAL.HOURS          SD
# 1:   1-2           10-06     42561.78    4297.287
# 2:   1-2           10-13     42177.88    4297.287
# 3:   1-2           10-20     44691.23    4297.287
# 4:   1-2           10-27     42709.28    4297.287
# 5:   1-2           11-03     44876.25    4297.287
# 6:   1-2           11-10     40582.44    4297.287
```

Comment: Actually `setDT` modifies `PayrollHours2` in place, thus it converts `PayrollHours2` to `data.table` too. So basically `PayrollHoursSD` and  `PayrollHours2` are identical... If you don't want to modify `PayrollHours2`, use `as.data.table` instead of `setDT`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! I'll adjust my function to as.data.table. Are you familiar with ggplot2 at all? In a nutshell, I'm trying to plot the most recent TOTAL.HOURS of my groups against the upper and inner fences created using the group's standard deviation. I'm trying to visualize whether the most recent TOTAL.HOURS value deviates from the norm for each group.

Comment: First of all, I don't think this is an answer, so no need to post is as one. Second of all, if you have a `ggplot` question you probably should post a new question and link this question to it